# How do I prevent `inline` element from overflowing while not wrapping?

Tags: css, overflow, inline

I have the following code:

```css
html, body {
    max-width: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
}

body {
    font-size: 16px;
    white-space: normal;
    word-break: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    hyphens: none;
}

code {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto; /* Doesn't Do Anything */
}
```

```html
<p>So as you can see, the <code>code element</code> breaks as I want it to</p>

<p>but this <code>"long" code element overflows</code></p>
```

I want the text inside `p` tag to wrap, whereas I don't want the text inside `code` to wrap, but I also don't want the `code` element to overflow, rather it's `max-width` to be `100%` and after that I want it to be scrollable.

Comment: `code` is `inline` by default, you have to make it `block`, or `inline-block` + max-width.

Comment: It is not clear what results you are trying to get perhaps some drawings can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this instead:

```css
p {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

it's simple & short, thus the final code looks like this:

```css
html, body {
    max-width: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
}

body {
    font-size: 16px;
    white-space: normal;
    word-break: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    hyphens: none;
}

code {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

p {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<p>So as you can see, the <code>code element</code> breaks as I want it to</p>

<p>but this <code>"long" code element overflows</code></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment told you correctly: in order to properly overflow the `<code>` tag, you need to give it a block internal structure. Also, don't forget about vertical alignment.

```css
html, body {
  max-width: 150px;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  hyphens: none;
}

code {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: red;
}

/* Only for example --> */ p { background-color: #fc08; overflow: auto; resize: both; }
```

```html
<p>So as you can see, the <code>code element</code> breaks as I want it to but this <code>"long" code element overflows</code> Now it works!</p>
```

*Run the snippet and resize the paragraph by grabbing the bottom right corner.*

Comment: Thanks, but I found another way to solve the said problem, and have posted it.